# How to do ListView correct refresh?

Tags: android, android-listview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a listview that receives an arraylist of objects and displays on the screen, that object arraylist is taken from a database in firebase, when I add or delete a document (object) from the database, the listview updates normally however, when I modify a single object field (document), the listview completely recreates that object in the view and "duplicates" each time a state field is modified.

This is my code that fills the list view:

```java
usuarios.orderBy("likes", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
        try {
            usuarios.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("Não consegue", "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.d("TAG", "New Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class));
                                doenca = dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class);
                                doencaArrayList.add(doenca);
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                Log.d("TAG", "Removed Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class));
                                doenca = dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class);
                                doencaArrayList.add(doenca);
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                // doencaArrayList.remove(doencaArrayList.lastIndexOf(doenca));
                                Log.d("TAG", "Modified: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class));
                                doenca = dc.getDocument().toObject(Doenca.class);

                                doencaArrayList.add(doenca);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                   ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCadPat);
                   ArrayAdapter adapter = new DoencaAdapter(getActivity(), doencaArrayList);
                   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Erro interno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Note that there are 3 states, one of adding (all right), removing (all right) and one of modifying (this makes the listview duplicate the object).

Answer (score 1):

When a particular data is updated in firebase database, onEvent of EventListener will be called and your list will get updated values but it still has old values. So, first, clear the list and then add data to it in onEvent method.

Something like this

```
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
   if (e != null) {
       Log.w("Não consegue", "listen:error", e);
       return;
   }

   //clear your list first
   doencaArrayList.clear();
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: This method erases all types of data from the ArrayList, even those that have not been modified.

Comment: Yeah, it'll. But again since you're iterating for every document, just add it to the list directly without using dc.getType().

Comment: But I'm not without dc.getType anymore?

Comment: Are you telling me to add off the Switch?

Comment: Yeah, instead of looking of DocumentChange, just get all documents from the queryDocumentSnapshots and then add it to the list.

Comment: But how would I get each state? "Added", "Removed", "Modified"?
This removes the switch from the cases

Comment: To get all data, you can do something like this  `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {}`

Comment: But reading all the data while updating always impacts the performance of the application too much, correct?

Comment: Yeah, sure it will. I think that's an another issue. Well, for better implementation you can use [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md). But implementing as I suggested will definitely let you get rid of duplicate values in the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206208/discussion-between-alok-bharti-and-luke-cross).